# How do I add another person as admin in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have started a Trello organization and would like to add another admin to my organization. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the organization profile page, e.g. https://trello.com/fogcreek.  You can get there by ...

   - clicking on your "Boards" menu (upper right) and then the name of your organization)
   - going to https://trello.com and clicking the "Overview" link next to the organization name
2. Click on the member that you'd like to make an admin
3. Select "Change permissions"
4. Select "Admin"

[image: Change Permissions]